# Bootstrap-Iso hosted locally in a css file is not showing glyphicons correctly. Need fix

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Bear with me..:I am attempting to create a form that will be input on a pre-existing site. I am not a professional, nor the developer of the site, so my intention was to create the form, which has js conditional formatting, in a bootstrap isolation css. The original source I used can be found here: https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap. I downloaded the files and dragged ONLY the bootstrap-iso.css into my host folder.(Not sure if I should be bringing boostrap-theme.css as well?)

I took out the form and the conditional js, but wanted to show you my problem in the code snippet. I cannot get the glyphicons to work with the bootstrap iso css, and need to know how to remedy the situation. Seen in my code snippet, only the envelope glyphicon works for some reason. When I link to "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css", the glyphicons work fine, but I lose the iso aspect and am not sure if the developers can just plop the form in. Can anyone explain to me how to get the glyphicons to work? I need to use them as tool tip hover overs.

```html
<link href="https://formden.com/static/assets/demos/bootstrap-iso/bootstrap-iso/bootstrap-iso.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-iso.css" /> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        </style> 
 </head>
    

<body>

    
 <div class="bootstrap-iso"><!-- HTML Form (wrapped in an isolated Bootstrap 3 div)
 
 
    <div class="container-fluid"> 
        <div class="row"> <!--Bootstrap -->
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-10">
            
            <p>Glyphicon user: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></p>

            <p>Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></p>
                   
            <p>exclamation icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span></p>
            </div>
            </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First it should be worth noting that you have two `<div>` elements commented out because of what I assume is a missing closing comment next to `<div class="bootstrap-iso">`. In addition to this, you're also referencing both jQuery and Bootstrap ISO twice, though I assume this was an attempt to get your Snippet to work correctly :)

As for your actual problem, you simply need to add the relevant CSS file:
`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css`

This can be seen in the following, where I've also corrected the comment and the referenced files:

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://formden.com/static/assets/demos/bootstrap-iso/bootstrap-iso/bootstrap-iso.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bootstrap-iso">
    <!-- HTML Form (wrapped in an isolated Bootstrap 3 div)-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <!--Bootstrap -->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-10">
          <p>Glyphicon user: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></p>
          <p>Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></p>
          <p>exclamation icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This absolutely works, and thank you for the cleanup. Doing my best. Will adding the relevant css file screw up any existing styling on an existing site? I thought that was the purpose of using the bootstrap-iso css file? Wouldn't I just reference the css link, without the bootstrap-iso file? This is just for my understanding as I am basing this all off online tools. Thank you VERY much.

Comment: Having worked with Bootstrap for more than half a decade, I'd admittedly never *heard* of Bootstrap ISO until this question was asked, so I'm not really sure about its constraints, but looking into it, it would only apply to elements within `<div class="bootstrap-iso">`. The core Bootstrap is outright **required** to have Glyphicons (or Font Awesome) working, so you will indeed need it. It **may** make some slight styling changes, though you should attempt to work around these. Referencing the ISO file **after** core Bootstrap will have it overwrite rules if necessary, so you should be fine :)